# Jest Mock Implementation is not working, instead original function is being called

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to test an API by mocking the database function, but the imported function is being called instead of the mocked one.

Here are the code snippets

```
const supertest = require('supertest');
const axios = require('axios');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const { app } = require('../app');
const DEF = require('../Definition');
const tripDb = require('../database/trip');
const request = supertest.agent(app); // Agent can store cookies after login
const { logger } = require('../Log');

describe('trips route test', () => {
  let token = '';
  let companyId = '';
  beforeAll(async (done) => {
    // do something before anything else runs
    logger('Jest starting!');
    const body = {
      username: process.env.EMAIL,
      password: process.env.PASSWORD,
      grant_type: 'password',
      client_id: process.env.NODE_RESOURCE,
      client_secret: process.env.NODE_SECRET,
    };

    const config = {
      method: 'post',
      url: `${process.env.AUTH_SERV_URL}/auth/realms/${process.env.REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/token`,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      data: querystring.stringify(body),
    };

    const res = await axios(config);
    token = res.data.access_token;
    done();
  });

  const shutdown = async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      DEF.COM.RCLIENT.quit(() => {
        logger('redis quit');
        resolve();
      });
    });
    // redis.quit() creates a thread to close the connection.
    // We wait until all threads have been run once to ensure the connection closes.
    await new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
  };

  afterAll(() => shutdown());

  test('post correct data', async (done) => {
    const createTripMock = jest.spyOn(tripDb, 'addTrip').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({
      pk: `${companyId}_trip`,
      uid: '1667561135293773',
      lsi1: 'Kotha Yatra',
      lsi2: companyId,
      name: 'Kotha Yatra',
      companyId,
      origin: {
        address: 'Goa, India',
        location: {
          lat: 15.2993265,
          lng: 74.12399599999999,
        },
      },
      destination: {
        address: 'Norway',
        location: {
          lat: 60.47202399999999,
          lng: 8.468945999999999,
        },
      },
      path: [
        {
          lat: 15.2993265,
          lng: 74.12399599999999,
        },
        {
          lat: 60.47202399999999,
          lng: 8.468945999999999,
        },
      ],
      isDeleted: false,
      currentVersion: 1,
      geofences: [],
    }));

const response = await request.post('/api/trips').set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`).send(tripPayload);
expect(createTripMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
expect(response.body.status).toBe('success');
done();
  });
});
```

The database function:

```
const addTrip = (trip) => {
  // const uid = trip.uid ? trip.uid : (Date.now() * 1000) + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
  const uid = (Date.now() * 1000) + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
  const item = {
    pk: `${trip.companyId}_trip`,
    uid: `v${trip.version ? trip.version : 0}#${uid}`,
    lsi1: trip.name,
    lsi2: trip.companyId,
    name: trip.name,
    companyId: trip.companyId,
    origin: trip.origin,
    destination: trip.destination,
    path: trip.path,
    isDeleted: false,
  };
  if (!trip.version || trip.version === 0) {
    item.currentVersion = 1;
  } else {
    item.version = trip.version;
  }
  if (trip.geofences) item.geofences = trip.geofences;
  const params = {
    TableName: TN,
    Item: item,
    ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(uid)',
  };
  // console.log('params ', params);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ddb.put(params, (err, result) => {
      // console.log('err ', err);
      if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'ConditionalCheckFailedException') return reject(new Error('Trip id or name already exists'));
        return reject(err);
      }
      if (!trip.version || trip.version === 0) {
        const newItem = { ...item };
        delete newItem.currentVersion;
        newItem.version = 1;
        newItem.uid = `v1#${item.uid.split('#')[1]}`;
        const newParams = {
          TableName: TN,
          Item: newItem,
          ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(uid)',
        };
        // console.log('new params ', newParams);
        ddb.put(newParams, (v1Err, v1Result) => {
          // console.log('v1 err ', v1Err);
          if (v1Err) return reject(v1Err);
          item.uid = item.uid.split('#')[1];
          return resolve(item);
        });
      } else {
        item.uid = item.uid.split('#')[1];
        return resolve(item);
      }
    });
  });
};
module.exports = {
  addTrip,
};
```

I was mocking the above database function when I was making a request to add API, instead, the original function is being called and I was getting the result that I had written in the mock Implementation.
What should I do to just mock the result ,when the function is called and no implementation of the original function should happen.

Even this did not give an error

```
expect(createTripMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Still the database function call is happening

I tried using mockReturnValue, mockReturnValueOnce, mockImplemenationOnce but not luck.

Can anyone help me with this?